# How can I use static lib in Shared Library project in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc

I have a Shared Library Project which builds only if I add -fPIC to the Compiler command ( this solves the issue ).

When I try to use a static library in this project I get a similar issue but in this situation I cannot fix with -fPIC:

```
libtest.a(exception.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Could I get some help please on how I can link this successfully ? I've tried adding -fPIC to the linker option also but I get the same error.

I am using GCC Compiler on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it appears you are updating the link time to add `-fPIC`, but you need to recompile `libtest.a` with `-fPIC` so that the relocations created in `exception.o` and the other objects in the library are PIC compatible.

Comment: Thank you @Jonah. I did that and I got rid of the link error.